# не работает запуск php в консоли

Tags: php, linux

```
php -v
```

эта команда не работает, никаких ошибок нету.

перезапуск php-fpm не помогает, в чем может быть проблема и как решить?

upd: в /bin/php пусто.

Comment: Что значит "не работает"?

Comment: @rjhdby, не выводит версию php

Comment: а то что исполняемый файл, не найден не пишет? Просто ничего не происходит что ли?

Comment: @teran, именно так.

Comment: А `echo $?` что говорит?

Comment: @rjhdby, в консоли? "$"

Comment: `which php` в студию

Comment: @TotalPusher, /usr/bin/php, но его размер почему-то 0

Comment: там скорее всего симлинк `realpath /usr/bin/php` в студию

Comment: @TotalPusher, /usr/bin/php

Comment: `/usr/bin/php -v` тоже не работает и никакой ошибки? тогда `/usr/bin/php -h`, `stat /usr/bin/php` и на всякий случай `file /usr/bin/php` - что перечисленные команды показывают?

Comment: @TotalPusher, проблему решил, ответ добавил. ваши команды из последнего комментария не пробовал. скорее всего они бы тоже не сработали, ведь сам cli почему то сломался.

Comment: @dasauser, переустановка - это последнее что нужно делать в Linux. мои команды как минимум показали бы проблему "это бинарник?"

Comment: @TotalPusher, php -v не работала, stat и -h не пробовал, file тоже, но ls -l показал размер 0

Comment: `ls -l показал размер 0` - вот от этого и надо было плясать

Comment: @TotalPusher, комментарий об этом я оставлял и вопрос обновлял

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема решена.

пришлось переустановить php-cli.

у меня это выглядело так:

```
yum reinstall php72w-cli.x86_64
```

Answer (score -1):

Для работы с php в консоли (в интерактивном режиме) используйте: "php -a"

Пример использования:

```sh
$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > echo time();
1554106866
```

PS. Если не установлен php, тут описано как его поставить:

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-debian-9
- https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-install-php-on-windows/
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.php

Если кратко:

```
$ sudo apt install php-fpm
```